# Is there any easy way to adding NSLog or any logging statement in all methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I am about to complete the project and I want to add logging in it. I know there are some good loggers are available in market(`CocoaLumberjack`). But for that I need to add log statement into each and every method. As project is about to complete there are lots of methods. So, is there any way or work around ? *Without adding log statement* into all methods If I will add at any central place and it will work for all.

I am not sure if there is such `Objective-C` runtime function that is called before every method.

This method will be helpful in all cases like I am or any new dev is writing new method then he don’t need to remember to add log statement.

**Edit:**

This is just for a debugging purpose. And I will add a way to control the logs like turn off and print detail of certain level.

Comment: Have you taken a look into method swizzling?

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this.  Seriously.  Users don't appreciate their log files filling up because of chatty software, and you'll also annoy every other developer by obscuring messages that are actually important.

You should only use `NSLog()` this way as an absolute last resort during debugging.  Even then, there are better approaches (e.g. you could use [`dtrace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html); if you get it to dump all `objc_msgSend()` invocations, you'll see almost all of your method calls, aside from those that pass through `objc_msgSendStret()` and the floating point ones if applicable to your platform).

If you *really must* make a chatty application, create your own log file, write your own logging function (ideally using [`asl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asl.3.html)), and it’s a good idea even then to have a set of flags that can be controlled e.g. from user defaults to enable different kinds of debug output.

Comment: What about logging to a private log file?  Surely that's not unreasonable?

Comment: That's what he said.
+1 because I like the word 'chatty' in this context. And I hate chatty applications.

Comment: @trojanfoe I believe I covered that :-)

Comment: But CocoaLumberjack can do that, can't it?  So "Don't do this" doesn't cover it at all.

Comment: I believe he wrote a little more than just "Don't do this." He explained it very well and mentioned creating his own log file.

Comment: I disagree; he is assuming the logging destination is the system log and suggests writing your own logging framework, when infact CocoaLumberjack can avoid both issues.

Comment: I believed NSLog always prints to system log, doesn't it?

Comment: The OP wants to use CocoaLumberjack!

Comment: @alastair: It would be great if you can add some sudo code about how to use functions those you mentioned.

Comment: @trojanfoe I think the question has been edited a couple of times, actually.  And I have no problem with people using CocoaLumberjack, but if their app is chatty, it should go to a separate file and not the system log.

Comment: Seems that I misread that! My bad. Sorry! :) Still a very useful answer here!

Comment: @lducool I did link to the manual pages, which have examples on them.

Comment: @trojanfoe Also, the title of the question says “adding NSLog or any logging statement”, so it’s far from clear that the OP specifically wants to use CocoaLumberjack (though that would be a reasonable choice, by the look of it).

Answer (score 1):

How about a category of `NSObject` with this override?

```
-(BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    printf("Excessive Log: %s\n", [NSStringFromSelector(aSelector) UTF8String]);
    return [super respondsToSelector:(aSelector)];
}
```

Comment: `-respondsToSelector:` is not invoked by objc_msgSend.

Comment: Put this in one of your classes, run and watch. Sufficient for what the OP wants, I think.